# How can I make nginx redirect (not proxy) traffic to a different port

Tags: nginx, redirect

I want to redirect (not proxy) requests for a list of hostnames to a different port using my nginx server how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a redirect one uses `return 302`, the requested hostname and path can be picked up using `$host` and `$request_uri`

So the complete config for the vhost looks like

```
server {
    listen 5.153.225.231:80;
    listen [2001:41c9:1:3ce::1:10]:80;
    listen   5.153.225.231:443 ssl;
    listen   [2001:41c9:1:3ce::1:10]:443 ssl;
    server_name tracker.raspbian.org;
    server_name tracker-bm.raspbian.org;
    return 302 http://$host:8000$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: If you are going to listen on 443 (SSL) you will also need the `ssl_certificate` and  `ssl_certificate_key`

Comment: Afaict you only need those in your "default" server block not in every server block.

Comment: Default server block is fine if you need a single certificate to cover every domain. Your answer doesn't mention it either way, which is why I added the comment for other readers who don't know